# How to keep scrolling by spacebar from jumping up on auto-load websites using Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, scrolling

I use the spacebar to scroll, as it's the least painful way for me to scroll web pages.

However, I've found that something has changed in recent history (this year, not sure when), that has caused unexpected behavior.

When visiting websites that offer continuous scrolling that auto-load more content (infinite scrolling), when I get near the bottom of the page and hit the spacebar, instead of loading more content and continuing down, the page jumps up to the spot where it last loaded content (often the top of the page), and the new content never loads. I need to manually scrolldown using some other method before I can regain proper spacebar functionality.

Is this a browser issue, or a developer issue, or a combination of both? Is there any way I can get the behavior I expect, by script, plug-in or browser settings.

I use Chrome, and switching browsers isn't a solution for me. It seems to work better in Edge, which keeps my place by "twitches" up and down a little bit before settling at my previous position.

Comment: just tried on 9gag (I think that's what you call infinite scrolling) and there's no issue at all either with firefox or chromium. I'm running Linux. So I'd say it's a browser issue. Can you give a website for which you have that issue ?

Comment: @pat Huh, it didn't happen for me on 9gag either, but that's the type of site I meant. It happens on Facebook and Twitter for me, but not on a Google Image search.

Comment: Facebook has no problem for my firefox and my chrome, maybe you should check which options you checked concerning scrolling ? Like autoscrolling / smoothscrolling (I don't know if this one is available in Chrome though)